# Use JSON.NET with oneOf, anyOf behaviour in schema creation and for validation?

Tags: validation, schema, json.net

Trying to build a schema using JSON.NET to validate a color provided as either RGB or CMYK

This should validate:

```
    {
        "color": {
            "RGB": {
                "r": 100,
                "g": 100,
                "b": 100
            }
        }
    }
```

this should not:

```
{
    "color": {
        "RGB": {
            "r": 100,
            "g": 100,
            "b": 100
        },
        "CMYK": {
            "c": 5,
            "m": 10,
            "y": 60,
            "k": 30
        }
    }
}
```

This is my schema (below), and have tried using min/max Items to do what (I think) oneOf would do. The reason I am not using "oneOf" directly is because there does not seem to be the ability to add this in code which is what I need using JSON.NET, instead of passing the schema as a string.
I want to be able to use JObject.Parse(...) once I have something working and I could not find any documentation related to oneOf/anyOf in JSON.NET. 
Any pointers much appreciated

```
{
    "id": "color_spec.json",
    "type": "object",
    "required" : true,
    "properties": {
        "color": {
            "type": "object",
            "required" : true,
            "minItems" : 1,
            "maxItems" : 1,
            "properties": 
                {
                    "RGB": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "required" : true,
                        "properties": 
                            {
                                "r": {
                                    "type": "number",
                                    "required" : true
                                },
                                "g": {
                                    "type": "number",
                                    "required" : true
                                },
                                "b": {
                                    "type": "number",
                                    "required" : true
                                }
                            }

                    },
                    "CMYK": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": 
                            {
                                "c": {
                                    "type": "number",
                                    "required" : true
                                },
                                "m": {
                                    "type": "number",
                                    "required" : true
                                },
                                "y": {
                                    "type": "number",
                                    "required" : true
                                },
                                "k": {
                                    "type": "number",
                                    "required" : true
                                }
                            }

                    }
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `required` should be an array of properties that are required. So at the root, it should be: `"required" : [ "color" ]`.  And likewise for the other properties. Could you elaborate why you're not using `oneOf`? How are you doing the validation?

Comment: @JeffMercado - Hi Jeff, I thought about `"requires" : ["color"]` but it still doesn't work as desired. I am using JSON.NET 5.0 and `Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsontovalidate)` followed by `JObject.IsValid(schema)` on the returned `JObject` and it still validates in the second case. I didn't think JSON.NET supported draft v4 yet, so I assume that is why oneOf does not work - an alternatives to mimicking this behaviour? thanks, P

Comment: Ah got it. I was looking at the spec but couldn't verify. There may be a way to do what you're trying but I don't know of any way yet.